# Bad request when filtering AAD groups startswith()

Tags: graph, count, filtering, azure-authentication, azure-rest-api

My tenant has multiple AAD groups, and our requirement is to filter the groups based on Display name that starts with `Test_` and perform some operations on those groups.

To filter the groups, I tried with the query but it throws bad request error

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=startswith(displayName, 'Test_') and $select=(displayName,id,createdDateTime)
```

And I am stuck with this error, can't get rid of it:

```
{
"error": {
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Invalid filter clause",
"innerError": {
"date": "2022-10-15T08:56:31",
"request-id": "5e5b8c28-e828-4181-81ea-f132ce8de323",
"client-request-id": "0490a086-11cc-9789-beb4-ebc708e8508a"
}
}
}
```

I tried to modify the filter query in multiple ways but no luck. In addition to that is it possible to get the count of the filtered groups???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have Azure AD groups starts with **`Test_`** in my tenant like below:

[image]

I ran the **same query** via **[Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)** and got **same error** as below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=startswith(displayName, 'Test_') and $select=(displayName,id,createdDateTime)
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve this error, try **modifying** the query like below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=startswith(displayName, 'Test_')&$select=displayName,id,createdDateTime
```

**Response:**

[image]

To get the **count** of these filtered groups, you need to include **`$count=true`** in the query.

Make sure to add **ConsistencyLevel** header by setting it to **`eventual`** while running query.

I ran the **same query** and got **count** successfully along with *filtered* groups as below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=startswith(displayName, 'Test_')&$select=displayName,id,createdDateTime&$count=true
ConsistencyLevel: eventual
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm stuck with this query. Appreciate your help